# iPhone Animated Sphere

Tags: iphone, geometry, textures, opengl-es-2.0, animated

I would like to build a sphere in opengles 2.0 that is animated. Basically I want to have a transparent sphere on which I have small images moving around randomly. I know how to make a sphere and to map a texture on it. I don't know how to add the animated images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be for the images to be individual objects rather than part of a single sphere. If the sphere is perfectly round, each image could be a square patch taken from the side of a sphere. The images could then be rendered and animated like any other object, rather than attempting to map them all onto one object.

It's possible to animate textures by changing the texture coordinates of the object, but I'm not sure if that'll work in your case. The motion is much more limited as you either have to move the whole texture as one piece or use multiple texture layers and sets of coordinates.